# Entity Framework loading foreign keys with HasOptional

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Is it possible to load `ProjectManager` by ForeignKey while using it

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.ProjectManager)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false)
```

I tried doing the following, and ProjectManager still returns as `null`

```
var entities = _context.EodRecords
            .Include(r =>r.ProjectManager)
            .Include(r => r.RecordLanguages)
            .Include(r => r.Department);
```

Comment: also show the full query as what you select can affect whether `Include` does anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't appear to have specified the foreign key

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.ProjectManager)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.ProjectManagerId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

---

Based on your error

> Contexts.Record_ProjectManager: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'Record_ProjectManager_Target' in relationship 'Record_ProjectManager'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.

Make sure your FK is nullable

```
public virtual int? ProjectManagerId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Why would this make a difference? Maybe there isn't even a `ProjectManagerId`, the OP might opt for independent associations (although not recommended).

Comment: @GertArnold my assumption was the OP was using FKs but just hadn't specified the relationship.

Comment: It might also be that the property just isn't declared as `virtual` in his case (don't know, 'cause he didn't show us his code).